# How to to populate field with data from different object

Tags: apex, soql

i have a problem with populating field with data from different Object. I tried something like this, but it say "Incompatible types since an instance of Schema.SObjectField is never an instance of String" in this row

```
newTransaction.CC_Account_Number__c = (String) Case.Currency__c;
```

Here is whole method

```
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Transaction__c> addNewTransaction(String dataJson) {
        List<Transaction__c> dataList = (List<Transaction__c>) JSON.deserialize(dataJson, List<Transaction__c>.class);

        Transaction__c oldTransaction = dataList.get(0);
        Transaction__c newTransaction = new Transaction__c();
        newTransaction.KLIP_Subcase__c = oldTransaction.KLIP_Subcase__c;

        newTransaction.CC_Account_Number__c = (String) Case.Currency__c;

        insert newTransaction;
        dataList.add(newTransaction);

        return dataList;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Case.Currency__c` is a reference to a field on the `Case` sObject. Its value is, as the error message suggests, a [`Schema.SObjectField`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectField.htm), used as part of the Describe API.

It's not clear what you're trying to do here. If you're pulling data out of the incoming `Transaction__c`, you need to use a reference into that object. If your `Transaction__c` has a lookup to Case, you'll likely need to be performing a query here to get the value of `Currency__c` from that specific Case record.